# Rails Server reload models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick

When I'm developing, I've noticed that changing some files requires a restart of 'rails server' (webrick) in order for it to pick up the changes; I've noticed this for models and action mailers so far- is there any way to avoid the restart, which takes a full 60 seconds or so on my machine?

Cheers,
Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not seeing a need to restart for anything other than the core Rails config stuff.  Models / Mailers etc should refresh happily in Rails in development mode.

Are you sure you're in development mode? ( which should be the default? )